# Does Seed Value affect the result of training data in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, analytics

I am trying to create a model with my data divided into training(70%) ,validation(15%) and testing(15%) set.After running the model I am getting some accuracy(ROC) and some Value for my confusion matrix.But every time I keep changing the seed value,it is affecting my output. How do I address this? Is this the expected behavior? If so how can I come to a conclusion of which value to be chosen as the final output?

Answer (score 2):

`set.seed()` defines a starting point for the generation of random values. Running an analysis with the same seed should return the same result. Using a different seed can result in different output. In your case probably because of a different split in training, validation and testing.

If the differences are acceptable small, then your model is robust for different splits in training, testing and validation. If the differences are large, then your model is not robust and should not be trusted. You will have to change the way the data is split (stratification might help) or revise the model.

Comment: @thierry.Thank you